# CSS Google fonts issue in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

I'm having trouble getting firefox to load a custom font from Google Fonts. I'm using the below code as recommended by Google, however this is not working in Firefox. It works fine in IE, Chrome, etc however.

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans');
body, input, select, textarea{
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

I found a few answers online that suggests removing the 'sans-serif' part, but this just causes Firefox to use its default font (which is worse than the 'sans-serif' one it picks).

Any ideas please?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using `@import`.

Put the `<link href` line into the `<head>` and call its name on css, like:

```
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

In your css file:

```
.my-class {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
```